# How to display an ampersand in a Windows system tray prompt?

Tags: c++, winapi, prompt, system-tray

I'm programming using C++ and WinAPIs. I've added a system tray icon using Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, ...) API. That icon also has an associated user prompt that contains an ampersand symbol in it, something like this, "View & Copy." But what a user sees though when the prompt pops up, is "View  Copy". I tried doubling the ampersand, like so "View && Copy" but that didn't help.

Does anyone have any idea how to display an ampersand in a Windows tray prompt?

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried *escaping* it ? Something like: `\&`.

Comment: Have you tried `&&&` ? If found [this link](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/30_2004_12_0_0_27845/Special-Characters-in-ToolTip.htm) where someone had the same problem and solved it using `&&&`.

Comment: @ereOn: Dude, you're genius! Post it separately and I'll mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, ampersands require double-escaping, like this `&&&`.

I'm not sure why but it seems to work.

My source: [this link](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/30_2004_12_0_0_27845/Special-Characters-in-ToolTip.htm).

Comment: Thanks for finding this. It worked. Who would've thought. I tried doubling it but it looked exactly as with one &, so I stopped trying. But who would've thought that it needed 3 of them )) Typical Microsoft!

Comment: And I'm not sure why that other answer gets up votes. It completely misses the point of this question. If I created the prompt myself then adding TTS_NOPREFIX would've helped .. doh... it's a no-brainer. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Why three (`&&&`)?

Answer (score 5):

It's not a matter of escaping the ampersand - Windows *by design* will [strip any ampersands from tooltip text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for a generally good reason:

> Many applications create toolbars containing tools that correspond to
>   menu commands. For such tools, it is convenient for the tooltip
>   control to display the same text as the corresponding menu item. The
>   system automatically strips the ampersand (&) accelerator characters
>   from all strings passed to a tooltip control, and terminates the
>   string at the first tab character (\t), unless the control has the
>   TTS_NOPREFIX style.

As you can see, the answer is very easy: you just need to add `TTS_NOPREFIX` to the tooltip class and you'll be set.

Comment: But I'm not creating a tooltip myself. I use Shell_NotifyIcon()

Comment: Get a handle to the tooltip and then add the class. You can do that any way you like, there are quite a few.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do you get a handle to the tooltip in that case?